# How to generate QR code that connects phone to wifi AND opens website?

Tags: qr-code

I know it's pretty easy to generate a QR code that connects your phone to a wifi or open a website. But I can't find a way to do both with just one QR code. Is this possible? If yes, can someone tell me how or mention a tool that does this?

PS: I hope this is the right stack to post this.

Comment: AFAIK you can't combine two QR codes into one. Therefore what you want is not possible.

Comment: You probably have to make your custom app which will get password and url in same QR code. Step 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818490/4287377  Step 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2201999/4287377

Comment: You might try a normal QR code that joins an open network with a captive portal.

Comment: @ChrisB well that's the approach I took in the end. But thanks for the answer, it might still be useful for others.